# Show Gridline on Y axis for 0 point only

Tags: highcharts

I have a HighCharts bar graph that contains both negative and positive points.

I have `gridlines` turned off but ideally I would like to have the grid line showing for the `yAxis 0` point.

I have tried doing another series along this point however this does not extend the full width of the graph and only goes from the first point to the last point.

My graph does not have `endOnTicks`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [plotLines](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.plotLines) with option `value: 0`.

Comment: Works a treat.  Cheers

Answer (score 3):

If all you want is the 0 gridline, you can use the tickPositions property:

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickPositions

set 'tickPositions:[0]' for your y axis.

If you want to highlight the 0 line and still have the other gridlines showing as well, you can add a plotLine:

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.plotLines

Comment: Cheers jlbriggs.  Seems like it might work but the plotlines suggestion below worked as well so didn't try this